# update only database tables imported from assets android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade

I have a database in my app. The database is composed of two types of tables one imported from SQLite file in assets, and other tables are created in the app by java code(queries) and insertion of data is done as the user starts using the app. Below is my code for creating the database.

```
public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    File dbFile = ctx.getDatabasePath("MyAppDatabase.sqlite");

    if (!dbFile.exists()) {
        try {
            //copy data base from assets folder
            CopyDataBaseFromAsset();

            System.out.println("Copying success from Assets folder");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
        }

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null,
                SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
                        | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Below is the code to copy data base from assets

```
 private void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = ctx.getAssets().open("MyAppDatabase.sqlite");

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = getDatabasePath();

    // if the path doesn't exist first, create it
    File f = new File(ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
    if (!f.exists())
        f.mkdir();

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

To create tables apart copied database, I have created new tables in onCreate of SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try {

        db.execSQL(//this contains the query to create new table apart loaded from assets);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, " Unable to create table", e);
    }
}
```

Now the challenge is that I want to update the tables that are copied from pre-defined SQLite file only and do not want to change anything in the tables created by the queries which contain user data. For that, I first dropped only that tables which are copied from SQLite file and then again called method CopyDataBaseFromAsset() as mentioned above:

```
if (ASSETS_DATABASE_VERSION != dbVersion) {

        //A and B are the tables copied from database
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B");

        try {
            CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The issue that's blocking me is that after dropping and copying updated tables, data of tables that are created from the query in onCreate method is also deleted and I am not able to find any solution for this after doing all research. Any help is much appreciated.